# I cannot get the exit status of a script run under timeout

Tags: bash

Here is a simple piece of a bash script that should run another script redirecting stdin stdout and exit status

```
timeout $time $assessment_tests/elaborato.sh $parametri < stdin.txt > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt 
echo $? > exit.txt
```

the first line works fine but the second line prints a '0' in the file even if the script elaborato.sh has encountered an error. Why?
Obviously without the 'timeout' command is printed the correct exit status. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example of `elaborato.sh` exiting with non-zero status while `timeout` returns 0? The exit status of `timeout` (if it allows its command to complete) is supposed to be the exit status of the command.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: `timeout 1 sh -c 'exit 42'; echo $?` prints 42.

Comment: As an aside -- unquoted expansion of `$parametri` is a potentially dangerous way to add extra parameters to a command. See BashFAQ #50 for more details on how it can go wrong and safer alternatives: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 4):

From the [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) man page:  (very first option shown...)

`--preserve-status` = Return the command's status, even if timeout occurred.

```
 NAME
        timeout - run a command with a time limit

 SYNOPSIS
        timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
        timeout [OPTION]

 DESCRIPTION
        Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

        Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

        --preserve-status

               exit with the same status as COMMAND, even when the command times out
```

Comment: There's more than one command named "timeout", but given the behavior (and that the others I know of pass exit status information through by default), I'm willing to bet that this is the one the OP is using; +1.

Comment: {Sigh}  I know, I saw that too.  Gotta try though, right? I verified that _mine_ had the option (I'd remembered seeing it), then searched for link.  Seems like the more 'unixy' systems (solaris, hpux, etc.) don't have it, while the 'linuxy' systems do.  There's also a `timelimit` command on my system too.  Yay for options!